# Linked list in C causing a memory leak upon creation and insertion

Tags: c, memory-leaks, linked-list

I have a linked list. It works fine but I was checking for memory leaks and realised that creating the list and creating a node for the list is causing memory leaks even though I go and free them later. It's saying there is memory lost due the malloc I create in both create list and insert. I can't go and free the mallocs because I need them, is this just a necessary evil or is there a way to fix it?
Is there anyway to stop these memory leaks?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "linkedList.h"
#include "macros.h"

LinkedList* createLinkedList()
{
    LinkedList* list;

    list = malloc(sizeof(*list) * 1);
    list->head = NULL;
    list->tail = NULL;
    list->length = 0;

    return list;
}

void insertLast(LinkedList* list, int entry)
{
    Node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode) * 1);
    
    newNode->data = entry;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (list->tail == NULL)
    {
        list->head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        list->tail->next = newNode;
    }
    
    list -> tail = newNode;
    list->tail-> next = NULL;
    list->length++;
}
```

How I'm freeing the nodes:

```
void freeLinkedList(LinkedList* list)
{
    int i = 0;
    Node* current, *temp;
    current = list->head;

    while(i < list->length -1)
    {
        temp = current->next;
        free(current);
        current = temp;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show how you are freeing the nodes.

Comment: You must free the list and nodes after you are done using them, of course. In a small program, you'll probably create the list early in `main` and destroy it at the end of `main`.

Comment: I did the freeing in main along with the free(list) at the end but it still saying memory leaks are occuring and it says it is happening in these functions

Comment: In the last addition to your question, the loop is not iterating enough times. For instance, when the length is 1, there should be one call to `free`, but you make none. Why not make the while condition `while(current != NULL)`

Comment: And the `list` itself isn't free'd. That together with trincot's observatio accounts for both leaks.

Comment: When I had it as while(current != NULL) it said I was freeing more memory then was allocated

Comment: I rather suspect that your `length` and actual number of nodes go out of sync. I suggest you do all list operations with node pointers and keep the `length` as informative value only.

Answer (score 2):

If the list contains length nodes then the loop in `freeLinkedList` should look at least like

```
while(i < list->length)
```

Also you need to free the pointer to the allocated `LinkedList` itself after calling the function.

Pay attention to that this statement in the function `insertLast`

```
list->tail-> next = NULL;
```

is redundant and may be removed.

Answer (score 2):

In `freeLinkedList` your loop is not making sufficient iterations. For instance, when `list->length` is 1, there should be one call to `free`, but this does not happen as the loop makes no iterations in that case.

Don't make it more difficult than necessary: skip the use of `i` and just use the more natural condition. Also free `list` itself:

```
void freeLinkedList(LinkedList* list)
{
    Node* temp;
    Node* current = list->head;

    while(current != NULL)
    {
        temp = current->next;
        free(current);
        current = temp;
    }
    free(list);
}
```

Comment: I free the list later in main but I'll change the while loop back. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to free `list` as well:

```
void freeLinkedList(LinkedList* list)
{
    int i = 0;
    Node* current, *temp;
    current = list->head;

    while(i < list->length -1)
    {
        temp = current->next;
        free(current);
        current = temp;
        i++;
    }
    free(list);
}
```